# Getting Mathematical Representation within Layer's Attribute Table using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, vector

I'v been playing around with Vector Coding and was wondering if there was 
any Plugins out there that might let me represent Vectors within a layer
as it's Mathematic attributes in the Layer's Attribute Table (Degrees and 
Length)

Considering there might not be one, can anyone help in Coding such a Function via Python?